# mixing asp.net and MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website which is functioning in asp.net webform application. Currently we are planning to convert this webform application to MVC with the following conditions.

1. New modules alone will be developed in MVC pattern.
2. Existing modules will remain in aspx page. ( no conversion to MVC).
3. Home page will be (default.aspx)

for example [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will point to [www.example.com/default.aspx](http://www.example.com/default.aspx)

new module which will be developed will have the following parameters.

```
 www.example.com/place/Japan
 www.example.com/place/USA
 www.example.com/place/(anycountry)
```

so I developed a controller named place.

### code:

```
  public class PlaceController : Controller
  {
    //
    // GET: /Place/
      [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

   public ActionResult Index(string country)
      {

          return View();
      }
```

when I type in the following URL :
http://example.com/ It goes to http://example.com/default.aspx

my routeconfig has:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but when i add the following

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          name: "PlaceController",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Place", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

and type in www.example.com it goes to place controller, instead of going to default.aspx page. How will I solve this problem

also if I type in www.example.com/place/japan I get **resource not found**. How should I be modifying the index actionresult?

Comment: Try modyfing the second `mapRoute` to `url: "Place/{action}/{id}",` and placing it before the other `mapRoute`

Comment: @I19 that worked, thanks. Now how will I point Index() action result to point to www.example.com/place/countryname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two actions named the name way ("Index") and that both respond to GET requests, because MVC won't know which one to use (**edit**: *unless you decorate one with `[HttpGet]`. and this will have priority over the other*).

So, in your Controller, you need to rename the one with the "country" parameter to "IndexByCountry". and then try this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Place",
        url: "Place/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Place", action = "Index" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PlaceByCountry",
        url: "Place/{country}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Place", action = "IndexByCountry", country = "" }
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Comment: also if I type in www.example.com/place/japan I get resource not found. How should I be modifying the index actionresult?

Comment: @Venkat that's because you haven't specified an action named `Japan`. You should call it like `www.example.com/place/index?country=japan`

Comment: but is it a way to acheive the same through www.example.com/place(action-name)/japan (input parameter)- I am ready to do changes to accomodate this.

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question, but yes, it is possible. You need to add a new route: `url: "Place/{country}/"`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I still get The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Can you try again? I modified my solution

Comment: Is there any changes to controller class? if so what needs to be changed?

Comment: Yes, the second action method must be renamed to "IndexByCountry"

Comment: works beautifully. thanks